# Trying to create an edit page link?

Tags: variables, quick-edit

Using a plugin and have created a page that offers more fields in a spreadsheet format.  To add these extra fields you simply click edit on the row you want to edit....

Now when I am in the plugins template and want create a link to the edit link for that particular post type I keep getting one data for one level down the loop.

In my specific example I have url:

xyz.com/learning/project/test-product

```
        <?php global $post;

 echo $post->post_name; 
print_r(get_defined_vars());?>
```

The post name I get is "project".  But when dumping my variables I see [post_name] => test-product.

Edit:  Later on down the variable list I see [post_name] => project.  So obviously I am capturing the later instance.  How do I capture the first instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `get_edit_post_link` function.

Usage:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_edit_post_link( $post_id ).'">edit</a>';
```

Your use of `global $post` and the other issue is a separate problem, you should ask a new question and provide more details ( including the code for the template being used )